# Is it possible to resize the child view of a UITabbarcontroller?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

So I got a storyboard layout like this:

UITabbarcontroller -> child1
-> child2

I was able to dynamically add status bar just above the UITabBar in the viewdidload method of child2 as so

```
    StatusBar.BackgroundColor = Appearance.ErrorColor.BackgroundColor;
    var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow();
    window.AddSubview(StatusBar);
```

Now the problem is, I would like the content of any child to move up when I said status bar is present

I have tried so many permutations and methods including increasing the size of the status bar and decreasing size of the child views to no avail. Help would be appreciated on this!

```
    UIView.Animate(0.2, () => {
        var frame = this.View.Frame;
        this.View.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(frame.X, frame.Y, frame.Width, frame.Height - 40);

        this.View.InvalidateIntrinsicContentSize();
        this.View.LayoutIfNeeded();
        this.View.SetNeedsLayout();

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **possible** , But the premise is that the **Y** coordinate of the view is just 40. When you hide the status bar, the **Y** coordinate becomes 0, and the entire View will move up.

In general, the **X** and **Y** coordinates of the Tabview's child view start at `(0,0)`, not from `(0,40)`, so your code below may not has effect.

```
UIView.Animate(0.2, () => {
    var frame = this.View.Frame;
    this.View.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(frame.X, frame.Y, frame.Width, frame.Height - 40);

    this.View.InvalidateIntrinsicContentSize();
    this.View.LayoutIfNeeded();
    this.View.SetNeedsLayout();

});
```

But the code is no problem, **all you need to do** is make sure that the size of the child view starts from **(0,40)**, then you will see the effect.

=====================================Update==================================

If transforming view is your want , coding as follow :

```
UIView.Animate(2, () =>
{
    var frame = this.View.Frame;
    this.View.Transform = new CoreGraphics.CGAffineTransform((System.nfloat)0.8, 0, 0, (System.nfloat)0.8, 0, 0);
    //change contained parameter can modify the level of transform , and even can back to normal status
    this.View.InvalidateIntrinsicContentSize();
    this.View.LayoutIfNeeded();
    this.View.SetNeedsLayout();
});
```

Back to normal status, replacing with this:

```
this.View.Transform = new CoreGraphics.CGAffineTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Good day, thanks so much for replying! Moving the view up works, but now it overlaps with the top status bar. Is there a way to compress the view and force the autolayout elements to recalculate the positioning?

Comment: @slushpuppy About adding status bar ,and need moving up view, this can not 
be understanded. Because they will definitely overlap. At least when view up , status bar will hide , this should be a normal logic.You can show image about wanted effects.

Comment: Thanks again for replying, so I guess it is not possible to just make the height smaller, without moving the view up?

Comment: @slushpuppy No, this is possible,code is no problem with resizing height of view.Just not understanding what effects you want.

Comment: Ah ok, so effectively I want to have a dynamic red bar that shows up, but when it shows up, it blocks some of the content in the content view. I then want the content view to be smaller without shifting the entire view up. Hope that clarifies the question, thank you

Comment: @slushpuppy Got it , Thanks for explaining .If question solved , thanks for marking answer in advance :)

Comment: Thanks again for prompt reply. So uh how do I make the content height smaller?

Comment: Thanks a lot, the height has been scaled down. Thank you so much!